# Background color of UIViewController2 disappears when passing data from UIViewController1 to UIViewController2

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two viewController. Whenever I change the background color of VC2 after passed data, the background color disappear if I try to pass data again.

UIViewController1

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func continuePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondVC", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            destination.name = nameField.text
        }
    }
}
```

UIViewController2

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var displayLbl: UILabel!

    var name:String?
    @IBAction func changeBackgroundColor(_ sender: Any) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let nameToDisplay = name {
            displayLbl.text = nameToDisplay
        }
    }
```

First I typed hello, and VC2's label become hello. And then I changed background color of VC2 by pressing change background color button in it. It became brown. I added screenshouts side by side.

[image]

I try to pass data again to VC2. It was another text. When I passed it to VC2, VC2's background color returned to red again.

[image]

Can someone explain why background turned back to red from brown?

`if let destination = segue.destination as? SecondViewController` creates new instance?

Why everybody use this method passing data from VC1 to VC2? As you can see if something changes in VC2, we can't get the changes.

Comment: O don't see where you are calling the action `@IBAction func changeBackgroundColor` in your code.

Comment: it is in secondViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must perserve the color if you want to it to stay by declaring it globally

and setting it in `viewDidLoad` , as every time VC2 is shown it resets with it's original background color

Comment: I try to do same proccess but vc2 to vc1 with protocol and change the color of vc1 background(background color change button in it not in vc2 and it works. İt gets the same color. I am trying to understand why we don't use protocols when passing data vc1 to vc2. Why we use protocols when vc2 to vc1.

Comment: Why I get the same color of background when I use protocol? Why I don't get the same color of background when I use above method?

Comment: anyway this solution helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let destination = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
```

does not create a new instance, it just takes a view controller created by segue from the storyboards. But the segue instantiated by the storyboard create a NEW instance each time it is triggered. Therefore you need to pass any data to it that you want it to work with.

Comment: I get it. With protocol it gets all changes, it refers the same instance. How does it happen?

Comment: @John what do you mean by protocol?